# Vuejs2- Avoid repetition of select field options using vee-validate

Tags: vuejs2, vee-validate

Iam using **vee-validate** plugin for validation. In my form, there is a select field in the table. Rows will be added dynamically in the table. I don't want to select the same select(Description column) option again and again [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IMFT.png). Hence I want to throw an error like "Selected description already exists in a table" this using vee-validate. Kindly help me to solve this.

Here is my code:

```
<template>
<div>
    <b-card>
        <div class="panel-body" id="app">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 20px;">No.</th>
                        <th style="width: 330px;">Description</th>
                        <th style="width: 130px;" class="text-right">Charges</th>
                        <th style="width: 130px;">Total</th>
                        <th style="width: 130px;"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="(row, index) in rows" :key="row.qty">
                        <td>
                            {{ index +1 }}
                        </td>
                        <td>

                        <select class="form-control" v-model="row.billChgDesc" v-validate="'required|check'" :name="'billChgDesc' + index" data-vv-as="Description" @change="checkRepetation">
                            <option v-for="option in billChgDescOpt" v-bind:value="option.value" 
                                :key="option.value"> {{ option.text }} 
                            </option>
                        </select>
                        <span v-show=" errors.has('billChgDesc' + index)" class="is-danger">{{  errors.first('billChgDesc' + index) }}</span>
                        </td>

                                <td> 
                                  <input class="form-control text-right" type="text" v-model="row.charges"  data-type="currency" v-validate="'required'" :name="'charges' + index" data-vv-as="Charges" >
                                     <span v-show=" errors.has('charges' + index)" class="is-danger">{{  errors.first('charges' + index) }}</span>
                                <td>
                                    <input class="form-control text-right" :value="row.qty * row.charges" number readonly />
                                    <input type="hidden" :value="row.qty * row.charges * row.tax / 100"  number/>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" @click="addRow(index)"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" @click="removeRow(index)"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                  <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" class="text-right">TOTAL</td>
                        <td colspan="1" class="text-right"><input class="form-control text-right" v-model="delivery" number/></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>

        </div>
    </b-card>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import accounting from 'accounting'

export default {

  data: function () {
    return {
        billChgDescOpt: [
            { value: '', text: 'Select' },
            { value: 'M', text: 'Maintenance Fee'},
            { value: 'W', text: 'Water Charges'},
            { value: 'P', text: 'Penalty Fee'},
            ],
        rows: [
            {qty: 5, billChgDesc: '', charges: 55.20, tax: 10},
            {qty: 19, billChgDesc: '', charges: 1255.20, tax: 20},
        ],
        grandtotal: 0,
        delivery: 40,
        selectArr:[]
    }

  },
   methods: {
        addRow: function (index) {
            try {
                this.rows.splice(index + 1, 0, {});
            } catch(e)
            {
                console.log(e);
            }
        },
        removeRow: function (index) {
            this.rows.splice(index, 1);
        },
        checkRepetation:function(){
             this.$validator.extend('check', {
                    getMessage: field => '* Slected ' + field + ' already exists',
                    validate: function(value){
                            selectArr.push(value);
                    }
    })
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.is-danger{
  color:  RED;
}
</style>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but a couple changes need to be made.  When you call `this.$validator.extend`, that only needs to be done once - when your component is created.  It attaches the `check` method to the validator, so then every time you have the attribute `v-validate="'required|check'"` in your HTML, it will run that check method.

In your `check` validator, you need to answer the question "is this value already selected".  The answer is to go through the `this.rows` and see if any of them have the same `billChgDesc` property.  Because this is in Vue, by the time the validator gets run, the row in question already does have that value, so you want to check if MORE than one row have that value.  So, something like this:

```
mounted() {
  var self = this;
  this.$validator.extend('check', {
    getMessage: field => '* Selected ' + field + ' already exists',
    validate: function(value){
      return (self.rows.filter(function(v){
        return v.billChgDesc == value;
      }).length <= 1);
    }
  });
}
```

This validator returns `true` if only one item has the given `value`.  I'm using the built-in `filter` method of Array (see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)).

You can see an example of this all working here: https://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/f9q50wx4/1/

Comment: It's working. Actually I got stuck in that validation and your information saved me. Thanks for your timely help.